# Leaflet lowest zoom level is still too high with L.CRS.Simple

Tags: leaflet

Trying to retrieve part of a district, however for some reason cannot see the whole area, even if zoom level is at 0, where (supposedly) we should see the whole world.
I am using L.CRS.Simple because this uses the [EPSG:3763](https://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/3763/html/) and cannot see that one on the CRS list. I am retrieving the data in JSON cause when tying with geoJSON, was not able to transform the 3D coordinates data into 2D planes ones.

```js
    const queryRegionText = "where=OBJECTID > 0"
    const geoJsonURL2 = "https://sig.cm-figfoz.pt/arcgis/rest/services/Internet/MunisigWeb_DadosContexto/MapServer/2/query?f=json&returnGeometry=true&geometryType=esriGeometryPolyline&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&outFields=*&outSR=3763&" + queryRegionText

    var map = L.map('mapid', {
      crs: L.CRS.Simple
    }).setView([-58216.458338, 42768.347232], 0);


    L.control.scale({ metric: true }).addTo(map);

    fetch(geoJsonURL2).then(function (response) {
      response.json().then(function (data) {
        data.features.forEach(element => {
          if (element.geometry.rings) {
            element.geometry.rings.forEach(point => {
              L.polyline(point, { color: 'red' }).addTo(map);
            })
          }
        });
      });
    });

    var popup = L.popup();

    function onMapClick(e) {
      popup
        .setLatLng(e.latlng)
        .setContent("You clicked the map at " + e.latlng.toString())
        .openOn(map);
    }

    map.on('click', onMapClick);
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Leaflet - testing</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css" />
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="mapid" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You haven't done any research on proj4leaflet, and you're assuming that zoom level 0 is the lowest possible.

Comment: Hi... I did saw that before but from the quick look i gave and from what I understood it does not support the Transverse Mercator from 1989. However it was not a very deep look onto it. There API say's it supports all this ones https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_map_projections and there is not indicating the one I need. Has for the zoom was not aware of that secondary functionality with such library. Will look a little more to it.

Comment: *sigh*. https://epsg.io/3763 , then scroll down to the proj4js section.

Comment: Hi ... Ivan , i did follow your advice and i read a little more about that library proj4leaflet. I come up with a final code that will place shortly here. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after some reading on the proj4leaflet, come up with this code. Thanks in advance for the comments and the reply above.

```js
const queryRegionText = "where=OBJECTID > 0"
const geoJsonURL2 = "https://sig.cm-figfoz.pt/arcgis/rest/services/Internet/MunisigWeb_DadosContexto/MapServer/2/query?f=geojson&returnGeometry=true&geometryType=esriGeometryPolyline&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&outFields=*&outSR=3763&" + queryRegionText

const map = L.map('map', {
  center: [40.14791, -8.87009],
  zoom: 13
});

proj4.defs("EPSG:3763", "+proj=tmerc +lat_0=39.66825833333333 +lon_0=-8.133108333333334 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs");

fetch(geoJsonURL2).then(function (response) {
  response.json().then(function (data) {
    L.Proj.geoJson(data).addTo(map);
  });
});

var popup = L.popup();

function onMapClick(e) {
  popup
    .setLatLng(e.latlng)
    .setContent("You clicked the map at " + e.latlng.toString())
    .openOn(map);
}

map.on('click', onMapClick);
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.7.1/leaflet.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/proj4js/2.7.4/proj4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/proj4leaflet/1.0.2/proj4leaflet.js"></script>
</head>

<body class="">
  <div id="map" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;"></div>
  </div>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR:** When creating the map, set the minimum zoom below zero. This should work:

```
var map = L.map('mapid', {
  crs: L.CRS.Simple, minZoom: -6
}).setView([-57728, 55296], -6);
```

**Explanation**

Normally, Leaflet translates from a latitude/longitude coordinate system to screen pixels using an assumption that the world is 256 pixels high at Zoom level 0. At each higher Zoom Level, the number of pixels doubles (explained nicely in the [Zoom levels tutorial](https://leafletjs.com/examples/zoom-levels/)).  With this assumption, the options for the map default to `{minZoom: 0, maxZoom: Infinity}` (as you are not adding any Layer that sets these values to anything different).

When you use `L.CRS.Simple`, at Zoom level 0 it maps 1 coordinate unit to 1 screen pixel.  Your data looks like it is about 18000 coordinate units tall, so it doesn't fit in your 400 pixel high map.  To make it fit, we need each screen pixel to map to about 45 coordinate units.  2^5 is 32, and 2^6 is 64, so we need to zoom out between 5 and 6 times.  Luckily, Leaflet accepts negative Zoom Levels, so setting zoom to -6 does the trick.  But to make it work properly, you need to set `{minZoom: -6}`, so the map doesn't get stuck at zoom level 0.  There's a good worked example in the [Non-geographical Maps tutorial](https://leafletjs.com/examples/crs-simple/crs-simple.html).

Using `L.CRS.Simple` should work for you, so long as the approximation holds that each latitude unit is the same length as each longitude unit (a square world).  Since this isn't generally true in the real world, using the Simple projection will cause some distortion.  If the distortion is significant for the features you are interested in, then you will need to look up how to use EPSG:3763 properly, using `L.CRS` and [Proj4Leaflet](https://kartena.github.io/Proj4Leaflet/), as suggested by @IvanSanchez.

Comment: Hi, thanks for yor reply, but i prefer to do things the best way possible.